# C# :Does Client machine need SQL Server installed on it while connecting to other machine having SQL Server installed on it (the Server machine)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dll, database-connection

I have written an C# windows application form which runs on a client machine and connects to SQL server on another machine.While building the connection in C# i have used dlls like

`1)microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.
2)microsoft.sqlserver.management.connectioninfo
3)microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc`

The client machine on which the aplication was built was having sql server installed on it.
so importing and accessing dlls was not a problem.

However on the other client machine on which i am going to run the C# windows application would not be having SQL server installed on it.

So will it cause a problem.Will the connection fail on that client machine due to absence of sql server.

If yes, what could be the way around to solve the problem without installing sql server on that client machine.

PS: I am asking beforehand to avoid the last minute hassle on the day of installation.

Comment: you don't put SQL stuff into a `Client` application. Use WCF / Web Services or other means of `Server <-> Client` communication.

Comment: No, the client machine does not require SQL server to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

The pieces needed to connect to SQL server are built into the .net framework. As long as you used those when coding the client piece you can connect to a SQL Database without MSSQL installed on the client.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

[SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx)

> PS: I am asking beforehand to avoid the last minute hassle on the day of installation.

You should always test locally first. You can probally get your hands on a random test machine to verify that everything is good to go.

Answer (score 1):

> So will it cause a problem.Will the connection fail on that client machine due to absence of sql server.

No, as long as you have all the required dll's installed along with your application.

> connects to SQL server on another machine

Not a good option though. I would recommend you to use some middle layer to connect to database. Perhaps web services. Something of the following architecture.

```
GUI-->Webservices-->DataBase
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you deploy the [Server Management Objects Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6375) (`SharedManagementObjects.msi`) when you install on the client machine.

This will install the SMO classes without having to install a full Sql Server install.

> #### Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects
>
> The SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) is a .NET Framework object model that enables software developers to create client-side
>   applications to manage and administer SQL Server objects and services.
>   This object model will work with SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005 and
>   SQL Server 2008.
>   **Note:** Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects Collection requires **Microsoft Core XML Services (MSXML) 6.0**, Microsoft SQL Server
>   Native Client, and Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types. [These are
>   available on this page.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6375)